# Backbone.js pass variable from router to collection

Tags: backbone.js

How do I pass the name variable from the router to the FriendInfocollection? Anytime I browse to localhost/app/person/MyName console.log returns a 404 for localhost/slim/index.php/person/

Can someone point me in the right direction on sharing this variable with the collection so it uses the correct url?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>I have a back bone</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="add-friend">Add Friend</button>
    <button id='view-friends'>View Friends</button>
    <ul id="friends-list">
    </ul>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script>
Friend = Backbone.Model.extend({
    name: null,
    age: null,
});
FriendDetailModel = Backbone.Model.extend();
FriendInfoModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    name: null 
});
FriendDetailCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '../slim/index.php/people/',
    model: FriendDetailModel

});
FriendInfoCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: FriendInfoModel,
    url: '../slim/index.php/person/' + name,
});


Friends = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function(models, options) {
        this.bind("add",options.view.addFriendLi);
    }
});
AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("body"),
    initialize: function() {
        this.friends= new Friends(null, {view:this});
    },
    events: {
        "click #add-friend":  "showPrompt",
    },
    showPrompt: function () {
        var friend_name = prompt("Who is your friend?");
        var friend_age = prompt("What is your friends age?");
        var friend_model = new Friend({name: friend_name, age: friend_age});

        this.friends.add(friend_model);
    },
    addFriendLi: function(model) {
        $("#friends-list").append("<li>" + model.get('name') + " " + model.get('age') + "</li>");
    }
});
var appview = new AppView;
var people = new FriendDetailCollection;
var person = new FriendInfoCollection({name:'Sean'});

FriendView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("body"),
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this,'render');
        this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);
    },
    events: {
        "click #view-friends": "fetch_list",
    },
    render: function() {

        var results = this.collection.toJSON();
        $.each(results, function(key, value) {
            var msg = results[key]['firstname'] + " " + results[key]['lastname'];
            console.log(msg);
        });
    },
    fetch_list: function() {
                people.fetch({
                        success: function(data) {
                                //console.log("success");
                        }
                });

    }

});

FriendInfoView =  Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("body"),
        initialize: function(name) {
                _.bindAll(this,'render');
                this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);
        },
        render: function(name) {
                var results = this.collection.toJSON();
                $.each(results, function(key, value) {
                        var msg = results[key]['firstname'] + " " + results[key]['lastname'];
                        console.log(msg);
                });
        }

});


friendview = new FriendView({collection: people});
friendinfoview = new FriendInfoView({collection: person});
AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "friends":"people",
        "person/:name":"personDetail"
    },

    people: function() {
        console.log('all the people');
        people.fetch({
            success: function(data) {
                //console.log("success");
            }
        });

    },

    personDetail: function(name) {
        person.fetch({
                        success: function(data) {
                                console.log("success");
                        }
                });

        console.log('one person named ' + name);
    }
});
var approuter = new AppRouter;
Backbone.history.start();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Two things **1.** this sentence is incomprehensible for me _"Anytime I browse to localhost/app/person/MyName console.log returns a 404 for localhost/slim/index.php/person/"_ **2.** Please make the effort to try to reproduce the issue in the minimal code expression possible, it's not very polite to just copy/paste your whole application code and let us make the work to remove the noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define routers like this :

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        'name/:name'                : 'getPerson'
    },
getPerson: function(name) {
    var callperson = new Person.Details({
        name        :   name
    });
}
```

Instantiate routes when dom ready

```
    app_router = new AppRouter;
```

Now you can access the name like this on your view:

```
    this.options.name
```

But you must define the options variable inside the initialize functions

```
    initialize: function ( options )
```

And for sure you can set the model like this :

```
    model.set('name', name)
```

Comment: he is asking about passing parameters to collection, why are you answering how to get is in view?

Comment: Say we have a collection named XXX, and it is used by two services, so we need to have different url for different service. eg. /api/a for first service and /api/b for second service, so the url function should be like this:
`url:function(){
    if(this.type==='a'){
    return '/api/a';
    }else{
    return '/api/b';
    }
}`
so how to pass the type parameter to collection when new a collection?

Comment: @YuC Backbone.Collection accepts `options` as the second argument in its constructor, so you can pass the service value as an option, and then set the url value within the initialize function of the collection. Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TZ9Kx/1/ .Many thanks for the negative vote by the way.